# .NET Core 3.0 worker - can't make logging work with Application Insights nor EventLog

Tags: azure, logging, .net-core, windows-services, worker

I need a .NET 3.0 worker service to log into Azure Application Insights and EventLog. None of this works (almost)!

Here's my `CreateHostBuilder`:

```
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    IConfiguration configuration = hostContext.Configuration;

                    WatchdogOptions options = configuration.GetSection("WorkerOptions").Get<WatchdogOptions>();
                    if (options == null) throw new WatchdogException("WorkerOptions settings are not set");

                    services.AddSingleton(options);

                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>()
                    // .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
                    ;
                })
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    //logging.AddConsole();
                    logging.AddApplicationInsights("<instr-key>");
                    logging.AddEventLog(new EventLogSettings
                    {
                        SourceName = "PNWatchdog",
                        LogName = "Watchdog"
                    });
                });
        }
```

1) **Whatever I do** the EventLog does not have any records from my worker. And I did set up logging level in app settings:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },
  "EventLog": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

2) **Application Insights** only get records when `.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService()` is commented out **and** the instrumentation key is hardcoded in the `logging.AddApplicationInsights("8d3bc77d-1cc3-4c4a-83e4-6d8aaa87f8f7")`. What should be done so it gets the key from app settings?

3) **Why is this so cumbersome?**

#### UPDATE

Here's the full `app.development.settings`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
    "EventLog": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    }
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "8d3bc77d-1cc5-what-ever-0000000000"
  }
}
```

#### UPDATE 2

**ApplicationInsights** added to **Logging** section:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
    "EventLog": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    } 
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "8d3bc77d-1cc5-4c4a-83e4-6d8aaa87f8f7"
  }
}
```

#### UPDATE 3

Property name changed for `Logging:ApplicationInsights:LogLevel`:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    },
    "EventLog": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information",
        "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
      }
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "PushNotificationsWatchdog.Worker": "Information"
      }
    }
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "InstrumentationKey": "8d3bc77d-1cc5-4c4a-83e4-6d8aaa87f8f7"
  }
}
```

Same thing - no records in App Insights. The instrumentation key is correct.

## RESOLUTION

Thanks to @peter-bons!

So I changed the order of `ConfigureServices()` and `ConfigureLogging()` and used `appsettings` from UPDATE 2 and it works now! So there we go:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args)
        {
            return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.AddConsole();
                    logging.AddEventLog(new EventLogSettings
                    {
                        SourceName = "PNWatchdog",
                        LogName = "Watchdog"
                    });
                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>()
                        .AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
                })
                .UseWindowsService(); // windows only feature
        }
```

Comment: RE the EventLog setup, if you set a custom SourceName or LogName, you'll need to run as administrator at least once to enable the creation of those to succeed. If they fail, logging will disable future logging and write a message to the default "Application/Application" event log with a message saying it failed to log. It's odd to see a custom LogName being specified at all, generally apps will log to the "Application" log. It's typical to set the SourceName to the application name.

Comment: Also, the log settings for EventLog in your appSettings.json file should be nested under the "Logging" object, rather than being in the root (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#configuration)

Comment: *What should be done so it gets the key from app settings?* -> can you post your app.config including how you set the instrumentation key?

Comment: I meant when using `.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService()` is grabs the instrumentation key but then no records in AppInsights. So the only way to have them there is to use `logging.AddApplicationInsights("8d3bc77d-1cc3-4c4a-83e4-6d8aaa87f8f7")`. In this case if I pass no parameter to this func I will not get anything in the insights also, and it doesn't grab the key from app.settings either even though it's there. Updated the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TIL there is something like a "Application Insights Telemetry WorkerService" :-)

I got it working using `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService`. But only if you either do not call `logging.ClearProviders();` or call `ConfigureLogging` before `ConfigureServices` otherwise the added logging provider is cleared.

This works:

```cs
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.ClearProviders();
                    logging.AddConsole();
                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                    services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService();
                });
```

using this config:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    },
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Information"
      }
    }
  },
  "ApplicationInsights": {
      "InstrumentationKey": "xxx"
    }
  }
```

As you can see in the output the AI key is correctly picked up:

```
Application Insights Telemetry: {
    "name": "Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.3b40adb096064da0816e7b8579aa443c.Message",
    "time": "2019-11-13T07:52:11.0027057Z",
    "iKey": "xxx",
    "tags": {
        "ai.application.ver": "1.0.0.0",
        "ai.cloud.roleInstance": "xxx",
        "ai.internal.sdkVersion": "il:2.11.0-21511",
        "ai.internal.nodeName": "xxx"
    },
    "data": {
        "baseType": "MessageData",
        "baseData": {
            "ver": 2,
            "message": "Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.",
            "severityLevel": "Information",
            "properties": {
                "{OriginalFormat}": "Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.",
                "CategoryName": "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime",
                "DeveloperMode": "true"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService() is the recommended way to enable application insights in WorkerService. It can take ikey from appsettings.json. This internally sets up the logging provider (applicationinsightsloggingprovider).

ApplicationInsights logging provider only captures logs of level 'Warning' or above by default (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service#ilogger-logs). So that's my first suspicion. Can you log something of Warning or Error and see if gets captured.
Or change the default level captured by application insights to capture info or trace level as well. (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/ilogger#control-logging-level)

Comment: 1) as you may notice I do have `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService()` commented out, so I tried to use that. I'm aware of it. But it simply doesn't work

2) Notice the logger settings I posted in the question. The LogLevel is **Information**.

Anyway, I tried all that. No sign of any records in App Insights. That's why I asked the question.

Comment: @alvipeo the loglevel for app insights is **not** set to information in your code. Read the second link in this answer a little bit better: App insights requires its own section `ApplicationInsights`

Comment: I do have this section. But as I wrote in the comment, the `AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService()` picks it up but nothing appears in the App Insights (when `logger.LogAnything`). So the only way to get something into AppInsights is to use `logging.AddApplicationInsights("8d3bc77d-1cc3-4c4a-83e4-6d8aaa87f8f7")` which does not pick up an instrumentation key from `app.settings` at all.

Comment: The pasted appsettings don't applicationinsights section. Please post the full appsettings.json - it should have applicationinsights:instrumentationkey, and logging.applicationinsights as well to control logging level. And use AddApplicationInsightsTelemetryWorkerService() only. Use this example as a reference: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/blob/master/Samples/WorkerServiceSDK/WorkerServiceSampleWithApplicationInsights/WorkerServiceSampleWithApplicationInsights/appsettings.json

Comment: Added, please see UPDATE 2. Is that correct now? I still see no records in app insights

Comment: Added UPDATE 3, still no records in App Insights.

Comment: You are clearing all providers. `logging.ClearProviders();` Please mimic the fully working examples from here: https://github.com/microsoft/ApplicationInsights-Home/tree/master/Samples/WorkerServiceSDK/WorkerServiceSampleWithApplicationInsights/WorkerServiceSampleWithApplicationInsights